# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /admin/controller/module/import_xls.php on line 8

Tags: php, syntax, ocstore

поставил себе модуль для ocStore версия 1.5.5.1.2
Версия php PHP 5.3

Теперь при заходе в модуль выдает такую ошибку

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in  /admin/controller/module/import_xls.php on line 8
```

Сам код

```
{
    private $error = array();

    private $data_to_view = array();

    private static $OPENCART_TABLES_WHITELIST = [
        // comunes/solo para v1.x
        'address',
        'affiliate',
        'affiliate_transaction',
        'attribute',
        'attribute_description',
        'attribute_group',
        'attribute_group_description',
        'banner',
        'banner_image',
        'banner_image_description',
        'category',
        'category_description',
        'category_filter',
        'category_path',
        'category_to_layout',
        'category_to_store',
        'country',
        'coupon',
        'coupon_category',
        'coupon_history',
        'coupon_product',
        'currency',
        'custom_field',
        'custom_field_description',
        'custom_field_to_customer_group',
        'custom_field_value',
        'custom_field_value_description',
        'customer',
        'customer_ban_ip',
        'customer_field',
        'customer_group',
        'customer_group_description',
        'customer_history',
        'customer_ip',
        'customer_online',
        'customer_reward',
        'customer_transaction',
        'download',
        'download_description',
        'extension',
        'filter',
        'filter_description',
        'filter_group',
        'filter_group_description',
        'geo_zone',
        'information',
        'information_description',
        'information_to_layout',
        'information_to_store',
        'language',
        'layout',
        'layout_route',
        'length_class',
        'length_class_description',
        'manufacturer',
        'manufacturer_to_store',
        'option',
        'option_description',
        'option_value',
        'option_value_description',
        'order',
        'order_download',
        'order_field',
        'order_fraud',
        'order_history',
        'order_option',
        'order_product',
        'order_recurring',
        'order_recurring_transaction',
        'order_status',
        'order_total',
        'order_voucher',
        'product',
        'product_attribute',
        'product_description',
        'product_discount',
        'product_filter',
        'product_image',
        'product_option',
        'product_option_value',
        'product_profile',
        'product_recurring',
        'product_related',
        'product_reward',
        'product_special',
        'product_to_category',
        'product_to_download',
        'product_to_layout',
        'product_to_store',
        'profile',
        'profile_description',
        'return',
        'return_action',
        'return_history',
        'return_reason',
        'return_status',
        'review',
        'setting',
        'stock_status',
        'store',
        'tax_class',
        'tax_rate',
        'tax_rate_to_customer_group',
        'tax_rule',
        'url_alias',
        'user',
        'user_group',
        'voucher',
        'voucher_history',
        'voucher_theme',
        'voucher_theme_description',
        'weight_class',
        'weight_class_description',
        'zone',
        'zone_to_geo_zone',

        // v2.x/v3.x
        'affiliate_activity',
        'affiliate_login',
        'api',
        'api_ip',
        'api_session',
        'cart',
        'city',
        'custom_field_customer_group',
        'customer_activity',
        'customer_login',
        'customer_search',
        'customer_wishlist',
        'event',
        'layout_module',
        'location',
        'marketing',
        'menu',
        'menu_description',
        'menu_module',
        'modification',
        'module',
        'order_custom_field',
        'recurring',
        'recurring_description',
        'theme',
        'translation',
        'upload',

        // solo v3.x
        'customer_affiliate',
        'customer_approval',
        'extension_install',
        'extension_path',
        'googleshopping_category',
        'googleshopping_product',
        'googleshopping_product_status',
        'googleshopping_product_target',
        'googleshopping_target',
        'order_shipment',
        'seo_url',
        'session',
        'shipping_courier',
        'statistics'
    ];

    public function __construct($registry)
    {
        //Call to parent __construct
            parent::__construct($registry);

        if(defined('IE_PRO_CRON')) {
            ob_start();
            $this->is_cron_task = true;
            $this->request->get['route'] = '';
            $this->request->get['ajax_function'] = 'launch_profile';
            $this->request->post['profile_id'] = PROFILE_ID;
        }

        //Check server requirements
            $this->_server_configuration();

        $this->_get_module_data();
        $this->_get_form_basic_data();

        if ($this->request->get['route'] == $this->real_extension_type.'/'.$this->extension_name)
            $this->form_array = $this->_construct_view_form();

        $this->setupClassLoader();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короткий синтаксис для массивов появился только в версии [5.4](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/migration54.new-features.php), обновите версию до 5.4 или если позволяет версия ocStore работать на 5.3, то просто замените синтакс на старый:

```
private static $OPENCART_TABLES_WHITELIST = array(
        // comunes/solo para v1.x
        'address',
        'affiliate',
        'affiliate_transaction',
        ...
    );
```

Comment: Помог переход на на php5.6